# Android Room Pre-populated Data not visible first time

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

Freshly installing the app, the view model doesn't bind the data.
Closing the app and opening it again shows the data on the screen.

Is there any problem with the pre-population of data or is the use of coroutine is not correct?

If I use Flow in place of LiveData, it collects the data on the go and works completely fine, but its a bit slow as it is emitting data in the stream.

Also, for testing, The data didn't load either LiveData/Flow.
Tried adding the `EspressoIdlingResource` and `IdlingResourcesForDataBinding` as given [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/dev-hilt/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/util)

#### Room creation

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideAppDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    callback: AppDatabaseCallback
  ): AppDatabase {
    return Room
      .databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database_name")
      .addCallback(callback)
      .build()
```

#### AppDatabaseCallback.kt

```
 override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    super.onCreate(db)

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      val data = computePrepopulateData(assets_file_name)
      data.forEach { user ->
        dao.get().insert(user)
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  suspend fun insertUser(user: User)

@Query("SELECT * FROM $table_name")
  suspend fun getAllUser(): List<User>
```

#### ViewModel

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      repository.getData().let {
        listUser.postValue(it)
      }
    }
```

#### Attaching the data using BindingAdapter

```xml
app:list="@{viewModel.listUser}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DAO returns `suspend fun getAllUser(): List<User>`, meaning it's a one time thing. So when the app starts the first time, the DB initialization is not complete, and you get an empty list because the DB is empty. Running the app the second time, the initialization is complete so you get the data.

How to fix it:

1. Switch `getAllUser()` to return a `Flow`:

```
// annotations omitted
fun getAllUser(): Flow<List<User>>
```

2. Switch `insertUser` to use a `List`

```
// annotations omitted
suspend fun insertUser(users: List<User>)
```

The reason for this change is reducing the number of times the `Flow` will emit. Every time the DB changes, the `Flow` will emit a new list. By inserting a `List<User>` instead of inserting a single `User` many times the (on the first run) `Flow` will emit twice (an empty list + the full list) compared to number of user times with a single insert.

Another way to solve this issue is to use a transaction + insert a single user.

3. I recommend you use [viewModelScope](https://manuelvivo.dev/viewmodelscope) inside the `ViewModel` to launch coroutines so it's properly canceled when the `ViewModel` is destroyed.

Comment: Now, I insert the whole list at once and use flow too.

But for the first time when collecting flow on viewModelScope, it gives warning `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
dao.getUsers().collect {
mutableList.value = (it)}}
```
I tried launching viewModelScope on ioDispatcher and collecting data on MainDispatcher using withContext but the same warning occurs.

Comment: After logging, I see that for the very first time, the flow collects first an empty list and then the filled list which is mostly the reason for skipped frames.

Comment: Basically, the flow is like app launches, he flow starts listening then pre-population occurs, and then it emits an updated list.
So, I guess what I need here is some sort of coroutineScope which is checked by viewModel and then only starts collecting.

Comment: collecting flow data using `collectLatest` does the trick here. 
Thanks to `Shreyas Patil` - https://twitter.com/imShreyasPatil